# Add files from "bash find" to 7z archive

Tags: bash, find, 7z

I did quite a bit of searching before asking this! (Even so I'm expecting to have a duplicate pointed out).

So I collect a bunch of files, e.g.:

```
find . -name "2020-*"
```

... is there some way to "pipe" all these files into a .7z archive? (NB I realise "pipe" may not be the right word as the operation I want is in fact a file-copy operation).

I've tried things like:

```
find . -name "2020-*" | 7z a -p pumple.7z
```

... this gives me ">" on the next line, as though it's expecting some console input.

So does the following:

```
 find . -name "2020-* > 7z a -p pumple.7z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the file names as arguments to `7z`:

```
find . -name '2020-*' -exec 7z a -p pumple.7z {} +
```

This tells `find` to look for files (of any type) whose name matches `2020-*`, and when it finds such files, run `7z a -p pumple.7z` followed by the names of the files. The `{}` is the placeholder for the file names, and `+` tells `find` to run the command with as many file names as possible in one go.

Comment: Thanks... There seem to be a couple of problems with this: firstly, it's not asking me for a password. Secondly I'm finding that if two files have the same **names** (but different complete paths), I get "ERROR: Duplicate filename on disk". I hadn't considered this aspect, but in fact the entire directory structure really needs to be zipped... so each file's path must be identified, and that path used. Maybe this is too complicated and I have to do it in 2 ops: 1) copy, 2) archive. I may need to use rsync for the copy op in fact...

Comment: The duplicate filename problem can be avoided by storing the full path (`-spf`). I’m not sure why it wouldn’t ask you for a password, it does in my tests...

Comment: Yes, brilliant! Thanks. I find that prompting for the password works if the archive name is in quotes, but not otherwise. This idiosyncracy is probably due to the fact that this is WSL (i.e. W10). Some Ubuntu distro, I forget which.